# Get Photos From Album Facebook C#sdk

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook-c#-sdk

i want to get album photos so far i have been able to get album info

I am using facebook c# sdk 5.0 for dot net framework 4

code so far is `dynamic friends = app.Get("me/albums");`
this provides `data` and we can get everything mentioned here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/
but i cannot establish connection mentioned for photos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so far i have been able to find this method if there is a good or different approach then please let me know.

```
//Get the album data
dynamic albums = app.Get("me/albums");
foreach(dynamic albumInfo in albums.data)
{
   //Get the Pictures inside the album this gives JASON objects list that has photo attributes 
   // described here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/
   dynamic albumsPhotos = app.Get(albumInfo.id +"/photos");
}
```

Comment: a am trying to get image of some page when they post new image!

Comment: What is app variable ? Can I create Test Method for get photos from album ? ***[TestMethod]public void Get_photos_from_album()***